# hibernate there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Tags: sql, database, hibernate

I know that this has been asked many times but the answers are not clear.
Why Hibernate does not allow this.
I was able to create a table with columns by had, where the ID column was part of keys making the  PK and Auto_increment.

The below block keeps throwing:

> hibernate there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as
> a key

```
create table rep (
        ID integer not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
        RepID integer not null,
        QNointeger not null,
        CNo integer not null,
        Value varchar(255),
        primary key (RepID , QNo, ID, CNo)
    ) engine=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Please show your mapping. When you get mentioned message? Do you use HBM2DDL ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a MySQL error.  I am guessing that you really want:

```
create table rep (
    ID int not null AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    RespondentID int not null,
    QuestionNo int not null,
    ChoiceNo int not null,
    Value varchar(255),
    unique (RespondentID, QuestionNo, ChoiceNo)
) engine=InnoDB;
```

That is, the `id` is the primary key for the table.  At the same time, the triplet of other columns is guaranteed to be unique.

Note that the column names in the unique constraint need to match the column names in the table.

Comment: Well in workbench, I have marked all 4 columns as PK, and it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can map that if you want. Also see here for an example: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-a-composite-identifier-using-an-automatically-generatedvalue-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Anyway, I would recommend you don't do that. It's just unnecessary to introduce a auto increment column next to other columns that are unique already. If the other columns together aren't unique, why not just use the auto increment column alone for the primary key? In relational modelling, a primary key should be minimal which is not the case if you have a auto increment column + anything else. If you want to ensure that a question is not answered multiple times, use a unique constraint to enforce that. Either that unique constraint is at the same time also your primary key, or you introduce a surrogate i.e. the auto increment column for the primary key purpose.

Comment: I had to add the auto_increment column because hibernate keeps requesting a PK.

Comment: But the composite, `(RespondentID, QuestionNo, ChoiceNo)` already is unique, so you could use that as primary key. Take a look at `@EmbeddedId`: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Embedded_Id